# C++ DLL Not Receiving Passed Variables

Tags: c++, vba, dll

I am trying to write a C++ DLL that will receive two long values, sum them, and then return the result. I'm doing this testing as a way to attempt to fix a 20+ year old C++ DLL that needs some fine-tuning to be 64-bit compliant and my skills in C++ are rusty at best. So I'm starting simple with basic math and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm calling the DLL from VBA but I don't think it's my VBA that's the issue.

C++ Header File

```
#pragma once

#define DLL_EXPORT _declspec (dllexport)

class __declspec(dllexport) CalculationApi
{
public:
    long Addition(long* value1, long* value2);
};
```

C++ CPP File

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Calculation.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "string"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

long DLL_EXPORT __stdcall CalculationApi::Addition(long* value1, long* value2)
{
    long return_result;
    string MsgBoxMessage;

    string Integer1_Type = typeid(*value1).name();

    string test_integer_text = std::to_string(*value1);

    MsgBoxMessage = "Value1 is: " + to_string(*value1);
    MessageBox(NULL, MsgBoxMessage.c_str(), "Value of Value1", MB_OK);

    MsgBoxMessage = "Value1 Data Type is: " + Integer1_Type;
    MessageBox(NULL, MsgBoxMessage.c_str(), "Data Type of Value1", MB_OK);

    MsgBoxMessage = "Value2 is: " + to_string(*value2);
    MessageBox(NULL, MsgBoxMessage.c_str(), "Value of Value2", MB_OK);

    return_result = *value1 + *value2;
    
    *value1 = 50;

    MsgBoxMessage = "Value1 is: " + to_string(*value1);
    MessageBox(NULL, MsgBoxMessage.c_str(), "Value of Value1", MB_OK);

    
    MsgBoxMessage = "Result is: " + to_string(return_result);
    MessageBox(NULL, MsgBoxMessage.c_str(), "Math Results", MB_OK); 

    return return_result;

}
```

And just in case I messed up the VBA here's how I call the DLL

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Addition Lib "C:\Users\micha\source\repos\CalculationDll\x64\Debug\CalculationDll.dll" (value1 As LongPtr, value2 As LongPtr) As LongPtr   

Function DLL_Testing()
    Dim value1 As LongPtr
    Dim value2 As LongPtr
    Dim Results As LongPtr
        
    value1 = 10
    value2 = 20
    
    Results = Addition(integer1, integer2)
    
    test = 0

End Function
```

The first messagebox in the C++ comes up blank... I'm sure I'm just not doing something right there but meh doesn't matter much. The second messagebox returns either 0 or some really funky number.  The VBA will return the result "583141696^" which of course is not 10+20.  Also the value1 doesn't get updated to 50, I'm pretty sure I'm not passing the pointer correctly as I've seen value2 update when I changed the value of value1 in the DLL.

This all seems REALLY basic yet it doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know VBA at all, so I looked up `LongPtr`. [It seems as though it changes size depending on the system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type). If you wind up passing a pointer to a 64 bit number into a function expecting a pointer to a 32 bit `long`, [the bad](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) will happen. Any way you can merely pass in 10 and 20 as values?

Comment: I just adjusted the C++ code to actually return good message boxes. Value1 shows 0 when being passed 10 from VBA, and Value2 shows 583011616 when passed 20 from VBA. And the function returns the same 583011616.

Answer (score 0):

I think Addition should be static :

```
static long Addition(long* value1, long* value2);
```

because if Addition is not static, a third (hidden) parameter (this) exist...

and the class CalculationApi is not really usefull here.

Comment: Good eyes. I hadn't even noticed the asker was calling a method. The ol' brain omitting unexpected details to make the problem easier.

Comment: I used the class because I expect to have more methods to include but it's a good point.

Comment: After updating my .H file to include static, now neither parameter has a value and both say they're zero and I also get a zero return value....

Comment: If you want the organization that classes offer but don't want to have to worry about class instances--the class is 100% `static`--consider using a namespace instead. That said, when you want an interface to present to the world from a DLL, it's typically best to stick with good ol' C. Everybody understands C. They have to if they want to get anything done. The DLL can be C++, but the interface should keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Well the suggestion to convert this to C instead of C++ paid off (after finding a dumb error of my own). Changes I made...

- Class gone
- Converted to C

I couldn't get the "static" suggestion to work but the code in C works fine without it. Not sure what's up there but I'm going to go with it.